# Win32 API for determining if a path is relative or absolute?

Tags: windows, winapi, path

Is there a win32 function that will tell me if a path is relative or absolute?

Thanks,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[PathIsRelative()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773660(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Beware - PathIsRelative returns 0 for "\\test.exe", even though such a path is treated as relative to the current drive.

Comment: "Beware" is excellent advice when using any of the shell path functions.

Comment: Beware - PathIsRelative() returns 0 for "X:some\thing", indicating that "X:some\thing" is an absolute path, when it should be considered a relative path - relative to the current working directory on the X: drive.

@Jason R. Coombs, I believe PathIsRelative() might be treating "\\test.exe" like "\\anything", which might look like a (partial) UNC path.  In what context is \\test.exe treated as relative to the current drive?  I have a program C:\test.exe.  When I CD to some subfolder and type \\test.exe, I get a message: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: I don’t remember what I was going for with that comment. It’s possible I was using Python syntax to describe `\test.exe`.  Or maybe I was experimenting with an edge case where I expected multiple backslashes to be treated as one. My comment about “relative to the current drive” makes me think I expected `\test.exe` to report as relative.

Answer (score 4):

As jeffamaphone said: You can use the Shlwapi function [PathIsRelative()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773660%28VS.85%29.aspx) to determine of a given path is relative or absolute.

But I thought I'd add that you can easily convert a Relative Path to an Absolute Path using
[_fullpath()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fullpath-wfullpath), and from an Absolute Path to a Relative Path using [PathRelativePathTo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773740%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Documentation for `_fullPath` has moved to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fullpath-wfullpath?view=msvc-160). Also it's almost always a very bad idea to use the ANSI versions of these functions when dealing with paths unless you are targeting a very old version of Windows. If you use the ACP / ANSI versions of the functions, your program will be unable to handled folders with names like 바위처럼 단단한/. You should always use the W versions of these functions, at least until UTF-8 support is out of beta in Win10.

Comment: @jrh rock solid comment. 10/10